# IBM Mobile Foundation v8 "Access Disabled" over access token expiration period?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I understand that Application Access control (e.g. Access Disabled) in Management tab of Console is to control application accessing protected resources, and found that the feature works in real time for adapter procedure calls and security framework related calls (e.g. Login).

The same feature, however, doesn't seem to be applied in "real time" for the use of `obtainAccessToken()` call in app when it's used in the beginning of the app, as the first API call.

Blocking the access of the app (even with the API call) happens once the token is expired (in other words, when the token needs to be updated).

[UPDATE]

- Using MFPStarterCordova iOS app with **cordova-plugin-mfp 8.0.2016122615 "IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation"**
- Scenario: Launching the application and obtained a token. Then setting remote disabled for the app, and clicking "Ping MobileFirst Server" button **without re-launching the app**. (I maybe was not clear on the term "real time" above, but I'm referring to this scenario - i.e. without re-launching the app - as real time..

Is this a normal behavior? Isn't real time Application Access control applicable to `obtainAccessToken()` API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

Based on your scenario:

> Scenario: Launching the application and obtained a token. Then setting remote disabled for the app, and clicking "Ping MobileFirst Server" button without re-launching the app. (I maybe was not clear on the term "real time" above, but I'm referring to this scenario - i.e. without re-launching the app - as real time..

While it seems like the first `obtainAccessToken` can continue be executed (until its token expires), it does not matter much, because trying to access any protected resource will fail once remote disable has been set.

That said, we're taking a look at it, but this seems like a non-issue.

---

In my testing the application was unable to access the server when using the `obtainAccessToken` API as the first API being used.

Note however that you did not mention if you are testing a native application or a Cordova application, nor the platform.

In my testing I used the Cordova Getting Started sample that can be obtained from the Download Center of the MobileFirst Operations Console. I used the Android platform.

Scenarios:

1. First I remotely-disabled the application. Then I launched the application for the very first time and tapped the button to obtain a token. This operation failed as expected.
2. First I launched the application and obtained a token. Then I remote disabled it and launched it again and tried to obtain a token. The operation failed as expected.

If the above is not the scenario you have tested, please update the question with the missing information.

List of plug-ins:

- cordova-plugin-device 1.1.4 "Device"
- cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.3.1 "Notification"
- cordova-plugin-globalization 1.0.5 "Globalization"
- **cordova-plugin-mfp 8.0.2016122615 "IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation"**
- cordova-plugin-okhttp 2.0.0 "OkHttp"
- cordova-plugin-splashscreen 3.2.2 "Splashscreen"
- cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.1 "Whitelist"

List of platforms:

- android 6.1.1

Comment: Thanks for the update, and yes, it somewhat makes sense in the context that the feature, Remote Disable, is mainly to control secure access to protected resources via integration tier (Adapters) for enterprise back end systems and to force users to upgrade. Please share any updates found from your further looking if any.